# Key property is unknown

Tags: errors, texlive, latex3, l3keys

i just updated my Linux distro (Linux Mint 17.3 -> Linux Mint 18) and from TeX Live 2014 to 2016. I have a (large) selfmade documentclass writte in LaTeX3.

Now I tried to compile a document using my class and get the following error:

```
LaTeX error: "kernel/property-unknown" 
The key property '.choice_code:n' is unknown. 
See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
```

I already searched the web, but the only hint was to update all packages, which I already did with no success.

Has anything changed at `l3keys` or any other LaTeX3 package, which could create this error?

#### Addition

I use the following code for generating keys:

```
\keys_define:nn {edu} {
    rmfont .choice_code:n = {
        \tl_gset:NV \g_edu_rmfont_tl \l_keys_choice_tl
    },
    rmfont .generate_choices:n = {
        computermodern, libertine, palatino
    },
    rmfont .initial:n = libertine
}
```

Comment: `.choice_code:n` has been removed from l3keys. You need to adapt your code to the changes in l3kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a documentation, why it was removed or how to replace its functionality?

Comment: `key .choice:, key / choice-a .code:n = code-a`?

Comment: It was removed in revision 5655 so you could check the repository log for information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clemens, Henri Menke and cfr already mentioned (thanks!!), `.choice_code:n` (as well as `.generate_choices:n`) were removed from `l3keys` in [revision 5655 of latex3](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/a137ea4d3322c45c8bf58034ba639179b98c09f0/l3kernel/l3obsolete.txt).

After rereading the [LaTeX3 interfaces documentation](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) (Section XX.3, pages 176-179), I was able to patch my problem. The example of the question can be adapted to the following:

```
\keys_define:nn {edu} {
  rmfont .choices:nn = {
    computermodern, libertine, palatino
  }
  {
    \tl_gset:NV \g_edu_rmfont_tl \l_keys_choice_tl
  },
  rmfont .initial:n = libertine
}
```

Finally, everything works again. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
\keys_define:nn { edu }
 {
   rmfont .choices:nn =
    { computermodern, libertine, palatino }
    { \tl_gset:NV \g_edu_rmfont_tl \l_keys_choice_tl } ,
   rmfont .initial:n = libertine
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was a little bit to slow writing my own one. :-)